# How to get synonyms ordered by their occurrence probability from Wordnet

Tags: java, nlp, wordnet

I am searching in Wordnet for synonyms for a big list of words. The way I have it done it, when some word has more than one synonym, the results are returned in alphabetical order. What I need is to have them ordered by their **probability of occurrence**,  and I would take just the top 1 synonym.

I have used the prolog wordnet database and Syns2Index to convert it into Lucene type index for querying synonyms. Is there a way to get them ordered by their probabilities in this way, or I should use another approach?

Speed not important, this synonym lookup will not be done online.

Comment: This is very specific. I've found this:
http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_0_0/api/org/apache/lucene/wordnet/Syns2Index.html
But probably you are already aware of this.

Comment: @Baltarsarq : thanx, yes, i have used this to convert WordNet prolog database into the lucene synonim index

Answer (score 5):

In case someone stumbles upon this thread, this was the way to go(at least what i needed):

http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/doc/edu/smu/tspell/wordnet/impl/file/ReferenceSynset.html#getTagCount%28java.lang.String%29

tagCount  method gives the most likely synset group for every word. The problem again is that synset with highes probability again can have several words. But i guess theres no chance to avoid this

Comment: Link is broken but a little searching turned up https://github.com/jaytaylor/jaws and, more specifically, https://github.com/jaytaylor/jaws/blob/f194da46211863ed2cdb1428bf2e21db21541224/src/edu/smu/tspell/wordnet/impl/file/ReferenceSynset.java#L148

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do another step (provided that speed is not important).

From the Lucene index, you should build another dictionary in which each word is mapped to a small object that contains the only synonym that its meaning has higher probability of appearance, its meaning, and probability of appearance. I.e., given this code:

```
class Synonym {
public:
    String name;
    double probability;
    String meaning;
}

Map<String, Synonym> m = new HashMap<String, Synonym>();
```

... you just have to fill it from the Lucene index.

Comment: I understand the idea, like you said before, what I need is seems specific: I know that the querying online wordnet returns the synonims by their probability, but I do not understand how is this probability information stored inside this prolog database (which i converted into index with Syns2Index you have linked before) How to retrieve that probability(and is it there?) information and map it inside eg class you proposed?? Thanx!!

Comment: Have you browsed this doc?
http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wnsearch.3WN.html

Comment: in case you  will need it one day : 
http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/doc/edu/smu/tspell/wordnet/impl/file/ReferenceSynset.html#getTagCount%28java.lang.String%29